# What does a "<private>" wake reason mean from powerd?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, logs

This morning, like every morning, I sat down at my laptop but this time the tabs that I normally leave open were closed and Photoshop was trying to quit.

This was totally unexpected so I tried to work out why this was happening. I went digging into the logs and then via the terminal I looked at the wake logs (see the last few below).

```
2019-05-24 03:38:54.643015+0100 0x6a068    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-05-24 03:39:47.402319+0100 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2019-05-24 03:39:47.402321+0100 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2019-05-24 04:42:14.169247+0100 0x28d      Default     0x0                  63     0    powerd: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2019-05-24 04:42:15.634941+0100 0x6a5a3    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-05-24 04:43:08.958830+0100 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
2019-05-24 04:43:08.958832+0100 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
2019-05-24 06:43:07.636797+0100 0x6abb3    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-05-24 06:44:00.846753+0100 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
2019-05-24 06:44:00.846755+0100 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
2019-05-24 08:15:01.640125+0100 0x6b1ce    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

.

There is one that seems different to the others (the one that says `Wake reason: "<private>"`).

**I was hoping someone may be able to shed some light onto what this is and satisfy a curious mind?**

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different. :) In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). In the meantime I wanted to let you know this site usually works best when each question is focused on a particular question, so I've edited this to focus on the parts relating to what's in your question title.

Comment: What is the data that the '63' represents? That column is all zeros except for this particular entry.

Comment: @IconDaemon raises a good point and has made me realise that your question doesn't explain what command you used in Terminal to look at the logs. Since macOS Sierra, the best command to use for investigating sleep and wake problems is `pmset -g log`. I suggest you try that and see if you can get something more meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with macOS Sierra, Apple started a total rebuild of the Console app and the log system.

And, as time progressed, Apple's increased focused on privacy has resulted in some macOS log entries to be redacted  to *hide* information Apple deems as being sensitive.

So, for whatever reason, the appearance of `<private>` denotes information that has been redacted from the logs. Unfortunately, this sometimes renders parts of the logs worthless in terms of troubleshooting a problem.

Regardless, there are many reasons a Mac can wake up from sleep and it's unlikely that it waking up was related to the problem you had this morning.